# CSS divs fit in gap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to making **responsive** boxes with different heights and widths. The problem is (as you can see in the image) is that they won't go in the gap and fill the remaining spaces. Anyone has an idea what causes this and What might can solve the problem?

[image]

```
        <section class="blokContentContainer">
            <div class="blok-25">
            </div>
            <div class="blok-25">
            </div>
            <div class="blok-50">
            </div>
            <div class="blok-50">
            </div>
            <div class="blok-25">
            </div>
            <div class="blok-25">
            </div>
        </section>

 .blokContentContainer  div{
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 2px solid white;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #B2DFDB;
    }
    .blok-25{
        width: 25%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    .blok-50{
        width: 50%;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .blokContentContainer{
        height: 100%;
        width:98%;
        margin-left:1%;
    }
```

Comment: That's the default behavior of `Float` elements in browser. You need to use libraries like http://masonry.desandro.com/ to achieve this effect.

Comment: You should use masonry - http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use fixed widths/heights (*i.e. not percentages*), then CSS3 columns could help you.

The trick is to use a combination of `columns` with appropriate `float` clearing. `clear:left` your bigger `div`s so that smaller ones can be side by side, but the bigger ones break out. Here is an example:

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/v8sjnfre/2/

**Demo Snippet**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { width: 100%; }
.blokContentContainer { 
    width: 400px; margin: 12px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; column-count: 2; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px; column-gap: 0px; 
}
.blokContentContainer div {
    display: block;
    background-color: #B2DFDB;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
.blok-25 { width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; }
.blok-50 { width: 200px; height: 200px; clear: left; }
```

```html
<section class="blokContentContainer">
    <div class="blok-25"></div>
    <div class="blok-25"></div>
    <div class="blok-50"></div>
    <div class="blok-50"></div>
    <div class="blok-25"></div>
    <div class="blok-25"></div>
</section>
```

The browser support for columns is pretty good (*IE>9*), with a combination of vendor-prefixes. See here - http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: @VinceVerhoeven: The browser support is pretty good (IE>9), and with a combination of vendor-prefixes. See here - http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Answer (score 1):

this is a common issue when using tiles. you could do the javascript yourself, or use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

the problem is the second row of tiles clears the entire first row. to overcome this you need to check the height of the first two elements, see if they're smaller in height, but wide enough, and move the first tile in the second row using `position:relative` and `top:-100px;`. of course this is only an example and the implementation depends on more conditions (fixed/variable size, sorting, preserving aspect ratio, etc)

Answer (score 1):

For as far as i know this is not possible with pure css because:

- Floats wont fill the gaps
- `display: inline-block` also wont work
- `position: absolute` and `position: relative` require manual aligning

Maybe take a look at [Jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 1):

By using css only you can't build tiling system, you have to use javascript.
The reason is that the height of each line is determined by the highest element in the line, unless you are using absolute positioned element, which overrides the default layout system.

But you will have to align the elements with javascript, I would advice to use tiling system library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList), if using angular

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to solve this issue trough css. But there are You can refer the following links Jquery [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need adjustable div's why can't you use jQuery Masonry
http://masonry.desandro.com/